Can the following rites be exempted from Nitya Upasana?
In the book Tripura rahasya , there is a stotra of the deity which is called as the gyan kalika stotram. It is mentioned in the book that one should maintain hygiene and take integral rice , water, flower , auspicious posture and then chant the stotra.
Can we not do this and simply light one Diya and chant the stotra? Will it give any benifit and blessings?
Also if I were to use integrated rice , can I use the same rice everyday or do I have to use new amount of rice every day ? And after the puja is it necessary to throw away the rice?
Please clarify on how to perform this stotra. Thank you.
